# Prove with induction if $A= \begin{pmatrix}2&1\\-1&0 \end{pmatrix}$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ $A^n= \begin{pmatrix} n+1&n\\-n&1-n \end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, induction

Prove with induction if

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$$

then $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

$$A^n = \begin{pmatrix}
n + 1 & n \\
-n & 1 - n 
\end{pmatrix}$$

---

For $n = 1$ we have

$$A^1 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 + 1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1 - 1 
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$$

so the base case is correct.

EDIT: we assume it holds true for $n$ (Thank you @gdcvdqpl !)

For $n+1$ we have

$$A^{(n+1)} = \begin{pmatrix}
(n+1) + 1 & (n+1) \\
-(n+1) & 1 - (n+1) 
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
n + 2 & n + 1 \\
- n - 1 & - n 
\end{pmatrix}$$

And also

$$A^nA^1 = \begin{pmatrix}
n + 1 & n \\
-n & 1 - n 
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
2(n+1) - n & n + 1 \\
-2n - (1 - n) & -n 
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
n + 2 & n + 1 \\
- n - 1 & - n 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So it also holds for $n+1$.

Is that correct ? We don't have solutions to this exercise. Feel free to point out any inconsistency. Thank you for helping me

Comment: you forgot to explicitly say that you assume the property to hold at rank $n$ in the induction step

Comment: @gdcvdqpl uh yes in fact, I will add that immediately, thank you very much !

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Isn't the $1 - n$ missing in the last matrix entry ? Did Mathematica output this ?

Comment: Ooops... it was properly computed, I mis-typed it.  Sorry.  Again:  `MatrixPower[{{2, 1}, {-1, 0}}, n] // MatrixForm`   $$\pmatrix{n+1 & n \\ -n & 1-n}$$

Comment: You accepted a **WRONG ANSWER** that was also fabricated by chatgpt. Wow.

Comment: @user21820 what ? why do you think it is wrong ? and it doesn't seem AI generated for me, why do you think that ?

Comment: @wengen: It is wrong. And it is fabricated by chatgpt; ask any Math SE moderator.

Comment: @user21820 Well possible it is a wrong answer , I have not checked it. But can you tell me where there is a sign that a bot produced this ? I cannot detect any such sign. Or do you claim that there are programs being able to detect (absolutely surely) such texts ?

Comment: @Peter: You can read the Math Mods' Office and judge. People's writing style can't change overnight, and there are many posts in that same new style with clear-cut fabrication.

Comment: Requests for [tag:solution-verification] must point out the  *specific* concerns or doubts about the validity of that solution.

Comment: @MartinR I removed the tag. If you have time, could you have a look at this question of mine ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4779666/let-k-cdot-be-ordered-field-and-x-y-x-y-in-k-conclude-from-order Only if you have time of course, I'm a bit confused because what I did seems too straightforward

Comment: @wengen: That is not my area of expertise. – With respect to this question: What *is* your question, if not a request for verifying your solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this question illustrates how finding the Jordan form, including the change of basis matrix, cleans things up.

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
-1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
2 & 1 \\ 
-1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right)  = A 
$$

and

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
-1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right)^n 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
2 & 1 \\ 
-1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right)^n  = A^n 
$$

while

$$
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right)^n 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & n \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right)  
$$

this last identity could also be done by induction, but is an example of the binomial formula  because $\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right)$ and $\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right)$ commute, while the square (or any higher power) of the second one is the zero matrix.

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Comment: $\bigcirc^{24}$. ${}$

Comment: @copper.hat  Thank you. But I don't know what $\bigcirc^{24}$  means.  The Urban Dictionary  seemed not to have it.

Comment: On my display the last two big circles are closer together that all the rest!

Comment: Oh, I get it now. I like putting  a line to separate sections. If I change the size of the browser window, the line may spread over two lines. Or, I guess, squeeze in some places.